# Difference of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

If $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are convergent sequences, and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n-b_n|=0$$ show that $\lim a_n = \lim b_n$.

I figure that I am supposed to use an argument by contradiction, but I keep getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L=\lim a_{n}$, $M=\lim b_{n}$. Then $|L-M|\leq|L-a_{n}|+|a_{n}-b_{n}|+|b_{n}-M|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.